# Shibboleth custom password flow

Tags: saml-2.0, shibboleth

I need to set up Shibboleth IdP to validate user name and password against a custom application.

Our application exposes a REST API to which one can pass a user's credentials and either returns a 401 on failure or a JSON object with some user metadata on success.

I was able to achieve this in SimpleSamlPHP IdP with a 30-line class, but having to switch to Shibboleth, I am having a hard time finding directions to do the same there.

Reading through the documentation the suggested solution seems to be to create a custom back end for the password login flow but the [Wiki](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/IDP30/PasswordAuthnConfiguration) does not explain in detail how to do this.

Can somebody point me out to some tutorials or sample code on which files need to be created or changed in order to do this (even basic examples of checking against a credential file or database would be fine)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for an [External Authentication Flow] (https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/IDP30/ExternalAuthnConfiguration)

For an example, see the shib-cas-authn3 project (https://github.com/Unicon/shib-cas-authn3). It uses the CAS Server to authenticate the users. It then creates an IdP session from information retrieved from CAS.

Comment: I was hoping to use the password login flow and just change the back end from the available ones (LDAP, JAAS, etc.) with a custom one. The external auth flow seems to require more customization than that. Am I wrong?

Comment: You'll need to write a class that knows how to communicate with your service and translate them to the IdP specific graph. You can update the password flow to use your class, but upgrades maybe problematic.